# grep ignore characters in the pattern

Tags: regex, unix, command-line, grep

The pattern comes from a variable of length 14. That string is a pattern to grep. Now the text file has lines that contain 13 characters each.

For example, the pattern of length 14 is

```
pattern =   58244804671021
```

and the text file contains

```
3823480467102
4724470467102
```

How can I make grep ignore the last char in the pattern?

Comment: But even if you ignore the last character, `5824480467102` is not there in the file

Comment: Well that the point it may or may not contain. The problem is that the keyword is 14 chars and the file has lines with 13 chars each

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, can you give clear examples please?

Comment: The input is "This is search word". Now I want grep to ignore the last character. so  "This is search wor"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your pattern is in `$pattern` and you are using bash, you can do

```
grep ${pattern%?} file
```

to remove the last character from the variable.

You can also use `cut` with character 1 to 13:

```
grep $(echo "$pattern" | cut -c 1-13 -) file
```

or even better in bash and ksh as a here-string

```
grep $(cut -c 1-13 <<<$pattern) file
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean some like this:

```
cat file
5824480467102
4534324435455
8244804671021
```

All line = `13` character

```
pattern="58244804671021"
```

Pattern = `14` character

```
awk -v p="$pattern" '$1==substr(p,1,13)' file
5824480467102
```

This removes last character of pattern and test it against the field `#1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter expansion as

```
$ grep  ${pattern:0:13} filename
```

> From Bash Manual
>
> If offset evaluates to a number less than zero, the value is used as
>   an offset in characters from the end of the value of parameter.  If
>   length  evalu‐
>                 ates  to  a  number less than zero, it is interpreted as an offset in characters from the end of the value of parameter rather
>   than a number of charac‐
>                 ters, and the expansion is the characters between offset and that result.  Note that a negative offset must be separated from
>   the colon by at least one
>                 space to avoid being confused with the :- expansion.

- `${variable:offset:lenght}`

  - `pattern` is the variable
  - `0` offset, or start
  - `13` length

**Test**

```
$ cat input
3823480467102
4724470467102
5824480467102

$ grep  ${pattern:0:13} input
5824480467102
```